# fully control and progress tracking on form data uploading (NodeJS/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to handle a form-data uploading process by an api-endpoint; But without other third-party modules like multer. Because I want to do something on files come from the client, change dimensions and quality (for images) and save a copy in several places.

So I need to be able to send the upload progress value to the client by web-socket; Because the uploading will not end as we receive the data and save it at the moment (like multer). Maybe I need to receive as buffer-data, then save text-fields and file-fields. But how can I do that?

For example: the client has sent a form-data with one text-field and one file-field;

I have searched before and found the below lines, but did not help me.

```
        const body: Buffer[] = []
        req.on("data", (data: Buffer) => {
            body.push(data)
            progress += data.buffer;
        })
            .on("error", ()=> {
                console.log(`⚠ error while receiving buffer stream ⚠`)
            })
            .on("end", ()=> {
                const requestBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
            })
```